# duplicate files on emby and squeezeserver

Tags: linux, zfs, kodi, squeezebox

My data file system is zfs and I'm running linux mint.

I had a buffalo nas that failed. After recovery I was able to save most of my files to a mirrored zfs on my computer. Something went wrong. Now some of my files show up as zero bytes. However, if I look at my media servers, kodi/emby and squeezebox, a lot of directories show up as double. One directory contains the zero byte files which are unplayable, but the other shows full files that work fine.

I would like to copy the files to another location and start over. The problem is the file system gives me the zero byte files instead of the good ones.

Are there any file system gurus out there that might have a clue on what's going on?

Comment: When you copied the files from the failing NAS, did the source data already have zero sizes? Did you check the copied data immediately after copying? Where hardlinks involved at the source? If yes, maybe http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/349697/how-to-restore-a-hardlinked-file is helpful.